# Pandas altering numerical data on import

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv file where a column of data is a 19 digit number of which the last three digits are always 163, this is specific to identify that this is the correct id. If i open the file in sublime, the column is correct, however, if I import it into pandas, these last three digits are different, and I can't work out what is happening. I have set the following option to prevent scientific notation as this should be a string anyway not a numerical number of any sort as they are id numbers not values and then imported the file. This is a file that I compiled so I know this data, it is for a database upload, but this issue is causing doubt as to what is in this file:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
df_api_data = pd.read_csv('api_manipulated_data.csv')
df_api_data['stream_id']
```

Here is what one of these values actually is, compared to what pandas is importing:

```
This is the actual correct id: 
8533312285629196163
7593893060854955163
9075665575245639163

Pandas is importing:
8533312285629196288
7593893060854955008
9075665575245638656
```

What can be causing the last 3 or 4 digits to be ransomised and how can I make sure these values are getting read correctly from the csv?

for clarity, I got the line:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)
```

from another stackoverflow answer on how to suppress scientific notation, and I had to modify it to produce no decimal point, as this is for a database upload so needs to be correct and as a result I can't confirm it is correctly implimented.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. It appears that large integars are a bit of a problem, but the data can be imported as string data by using dtype as object as follows:

```
df_api_data = pd.read_csv('api_manipulated_data.csv', dtype=object)
```

the data is now displaying correctly.